# Orchard Permission To One Particular Blog

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

IS there a way to limit user permission to only manage one blog instead all blogs?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Did you try the module `Orchard.ContentPermissions` already?

Comment: You could code your own permission for that, take a look at this: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Blogs/Permissions.cs